# How to properly get an index from an array and do some operation with that?

Tags: java, java-stream, indexof

What I'm trying to do here is to find a sum of a squared value of each element of the array. In `while(no>-1)` loop, for each iteration, I located an element that has the biggest value. After that, I decreased that value by 1.

Here's the thing. When reached the point where there are multiple maximum values remained in the array, subtracting didn't work. It would be much appreciated If you guys could help me out. Thank you.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
class NoOvertime {
    public int noOvertime(int no, int[] works) {
        int result = 0;
        int[] temp = works;
        int index =0;
        int maxval =0;
        while(no>-1){
            maxval = Arrays.stream(temp).max().getAsInt();
            System.out.println(maxval);
            index =Arrays.asList(temp).indexOf(maxval)+1;
            temp[index]= temp[index]-1;
            no--;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<works.length;i++){
            result += works[i]*works[i];
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NoOvertime c = new NoOvertime();
        int []test = {7,5,3};
        System.out.println(c.noOvertime(4,test));
    }
}
```

what I get after executing the code is this:

```
7
6
5
5
5
38
```

Comment: I dont understand what you trying to do.  But one thing I noticed is that works and temp are the same.  Did you mean for temp to be a copy of work, vs being work by a different name?

Comment: Write in plain English, what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I’m also unsure what you’re trying to do, but Arrays.asList(temp) doesn’t do what you think.

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(temp)` makes a `List<int[]>` (containing exactly 1 int[] item), not a `List<Integer>`. Hence, your `index` is always 0 because `indexOf` will always return -1.